# What is the difference between javax.net.ssl.keyStore and server.ssl.key-store properties when specifying keystore for a SpringBoot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, keystore, jks

1. Can I specify keystore using either of these properties - the Java-specific javax.net.ssl.keyStore  or the spring boot specific server.ssl.key-store. Any differences? I would like to use the keystore for serving my app using https as well as mutual client authentication with some REST services
2. Can the SpringBoot application be served using https if the keystore is not specified as a property or jvm argument, rather is read at the startup using custom code? Or does the keystore specification have to come before that if the app has to be served using https?

Comment: Ever figure it out I am wondering the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those two properties have complementary roles:

- `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` is a **system** property used by the Java security providers to configure the default `SSLContext`. Most SSL **clients** use the default `SSLContext`.

  You don't need to pass this property as `-D` argument to the JVM, you can set it programmatically at a very **early** stage of your application startup, but I would advise against it: since your application may not be the only application in the JVM (e.g. your run it as WAR archive), you will influence the behavior of other applications. Use a non-default `SSLContext` instead.
- `server.ssl.keyStore` is a **Spring** property to configure the **server** socket of the embedded servlet container. It can come from [many different sources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config).

  While in theory a servlet container can use the default `SSLContext` and retrieve its certificate from the default `KeyManager` (which loads its keys from the keystore specified through `javax.net.ssl.keyStore`), I don't know any servlet container that would actually do it.

  Usually the certificate used as SSL client is not the same as the one used as SSL server.