# Defining trust-store and key-store information in spring boot application with external tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, keystore, truststore, server.xml

I have configured my trustsore and keystore information in the external tomcat's server.xml in the Connector tag. The certificates are stored in the tomcat's /base/lib directory.
I need to deploy a spring boot application to this external tomcat.

1. How can I make the information about trustsore and keystore  available to the spring boot application?
2. Where in the spring boot application do I need to store the trsustore and keystore .jks files?

I did the same with the datasource in Resource tag in server.xml, and in spring boot application I used
**spring.datasource.jndi-name=some name to jndi**. How can I configure the same for trsustore and keystore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keystore and truststore in Tomcat's `<Connector>` have a single purpose:

- the keystore contains the certificate (and private key) used by the server's SSL port,
- the truststore contains the list of CAs, which are trusted if [mutual SSL authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication#mTLS) is enabled.

Therefore these settings are specific to each deployment of your application. You shouldn't provide them yourself.

You should only provide system administrators a way to configure those settings. In your case **Spring Boot** already takes care of it (cf. [server.ssl properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-ssl)).

#### See also:

- [What is the difference between javax.net.ssl.keyStore and server.ssl.key-store properties when specifying keystore for a SpringBoot app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61072648/11748454)

Comment: Does it means I am not supposed to configure any properties in application.properties, since these properties server.* properties are for embedded tomcat

Comment: I wouldn't set any `server.ssl.*` properties in `application.properties`, this way the default protocol remains plain HTTP. If the system administrator wants to enable SSL, he can do it with an external configuration file. You can find a similar default configuration in Tomcat: there is only a plain connector configured by default, if you want to enable SSL you must do it yourself.

Comment: system administrator already instructed that the ssl is configured in server.xml  of external tomcat, just need to make the spring boot application make use of these, thats the question, How to make spring boot application know that trusttore and keystore and configured in external tomcat .

Comment: When deployed as a WAR file (in an external Tomcat e.g.), there is no need to specify anything, the servlet container will take care of opening the SSL socket and forward the request to the appropriate application.